# How do I change the user I am logged in with on Network Share?

Tags: windows-10, network-shares

The normal answer seems to be to use

```
net use \\SHARE
```

However this doesn't work for me (using windows 10)

```
net use
New connections will be remembered.

There are no entries in the list.
```

However, if I access the share, say \192.168.1.100 in explorer, I am in, with the access rights of a user I logged in as 6 months ago.  I want to log in as different user.

So I did:

```
net use \\192.168.1.100 * /user:username
```

Then I entered the password, and I get the error

```
Type the password for \\192.168.1.100:
System error 1219 has occurred.

Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one 
user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or 
shared resource and try again.
```

How do I actually disconnect and connect as a new user?

I know this is a duplicate, however as I am not allowed to comment, I have to create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

First you must delete the share, before accessing it as a different user.

```
net share \\192.168.1.100 del
```

Then re-access it

```
net use \\192.168.1.100 * /user:username
```

Comment: As you can see above, there are no existing connections when doing "net use", so the net use /delete doesn't do anything.  That's really the reason for my question. how to disconnect when nothing is listed.

Comment: Ah ok weird, only other thing I can think of @wcndave is saved credentials existing for that connection, though it doesn't really make sense.